# Additional fields in Prestashop module - changes not displaing, parse error & class missing

Tags: module, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I'm usually working with WP, but I need to manipulate a module [blockcontactinfos](https://github.com/PrestaShop/blockcontactinfos) on Prestashop - just simply add two more fields which will be shown on the front end, but somehow it's not working.

I have carrefully copied one of the fields, changed it everywhere but I when trying to clear the cache (in the Performance menu):

```
2 errors 
blockcontactinfos (parse error in /modules/blockcontactinfos/blockcontactinfos.php)
blockcontactinfos (class missing in /modules/blockcontactinfos/blockcontactinfos.php)
```

Could anybody help me out of this? Thanks a lot in advance. Prestashop is 1.6. Fields are displayed correctly in settings, values saved, but there is the error above and I just can't force the web page to load changed template file.

blockcontactinfos.php (added the ones with `_url`), lines 31-141, changes marked with `// KV`:

```
<?php         
if (!defined('_CAN_LOAD_FILES_'))
    exit;

class Blockcontactinfos extends Module
{
    protected static $contact_fields = array(
        'BLOCKCONTACTINFOS_COMPANY',
        'BLOCKCONTACTINFOS_ADDRESS',
        'BLOCKCONTACTINFOS_ADDRESS_URL',
        'BLOCKCONTACTINFOS_PHONE',
        'BLOCKCONTACTINFOS_PHONE_URL',
        'BLOCKCONTACTINFOS_EMAIL',
    );

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'blockcontactinfos';
        $this->author = 'PrestaShop';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.2.0';

        $this->bootstrap = true;
        parent::__construct();  

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Contact information block');
        $this->description = $this->l('This module will allow you to display your e-store\'s contact information in a customizable block.');
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
    }

    public function install()
    {
        Configuration::updateValue('BLOCKCONTACTINFOS_COMPANY', Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_NAME'));
        Configuration::updateValue('BLOCKCONTACTINFOS_ADDRESS', trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_ADDR1').' '.Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_ADDR2')."\n".Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_CODE').' '.Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_CITY')."\n".Country::getNameById(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'), Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_COUNTRY_ID')))));
        Configuration::updateValue('BLOCKCONTACTINFOS_ADDRESS_URL', Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_ADDRESS_URL'));      
        Configuration::updateValue('BLOCKCONTACTINFOS_PHONE', Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_PHONE'));
        Configuration::updateValue('BLOCKCONTACTINFOS_PHONE_URL', Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_PHONE_URL'));
        Configuration::updateValue('BLOCKCONTACTINFOS_EMAIL', Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_EMAIL'));
        $this->_clearCache('blockcontactinfos.tpl');
        return (parent::install() && $this->registerHook('header') && $this->registerHook('footer'));
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        foreach (Blockcontactinfos::$contact_fields as $field)
            Configuration::deleteByName($field);
        return (parent::uninstall());
    }

    public function getContent()
    {
        $html = '';
        if (Tools::isSubmit('submitModule'))
        {   
            foreach (Blockcontactinfos::$contact_fields as $field)
                Configuration::updateValue($field, Tools::getValue($field));
            $this->_clearCache('blockcontactinfos.tpl');
            $html = $this->displayConfirmation($this->l('Configuration updated'));
        }

        return $html.$this->renderForm();
    }

    public function hookHeader()
    {
        $this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path).'blockcontactinfos.css', 'all');
    }

    public function hookFooter($params)
    {   
        if (!$this->isCached('blockcontactinfos.tpl', $this->getCacheId()))
            foreach (Blockcontactinfos::$contact_fields as $field)
                $this->smarty->assign(strtolower($field), Configuration::get($field));
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'blockcontactinfos.tpl', $this->getCacheId());
    }

    public function renderForm()
    {
        $fields_form = array(
            'form' => array(
                'legend' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
                    'icon' => 'icon-cogs'
                ),
                'input' => array(
                    array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => $this->l('Company name'),
                        'name' => 'BLOCKCONTACTINFOS_COMPANY',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'textarea',
                        'label' => $this->l('Address'),
                        'name' => 'BLOCKCONTACTINFOS_ADDRESS',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => $this->l('URL na Google mapy'),
                        'name' => 'BLOCKCONTACTINFOS_ADDRESS_URL',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => $this->l('Phone number'),
                        'name' => 'BLOCKCONTACTINFOS_PHONE',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => $this->l('Telefonní číslo bez mezer'),
                        'name' => 'BLOCKCONTACTINFOS_PHONE_URL',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => $this->l('Email'),
                        'name' => 'BLOCKCONTACTINFOS_EMAIL',
                    ),
                ),
                'submit' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Save')
                )
            ),
        );

        $helper = new HelperForm();
        $helper->show_toolbar = false;
        $helper->table =  $this->table;
        $lang = new Language((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));
        $helper->default_form_language = $lang->id;
        $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = Configuration::get('PS_BO_ALLOW_EMPLOYEE_FORM_LANG') ? Configuration::get('PS_BO_ALLOW_EMPLOYEE_FORM_LANG') : 0;
        $this->fields_form = array();

        $helper->identifier = $this->identifier;
        $helper->submit_action = 'submitModule';
        $helper->currentIndex = $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminModules', false).'&configure='.$this->name.'&tab_module='.$this->tab.'&module_name='.$this->name;
        $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
        $helper->tpl_vars = array(
            'fields_value' => array(),
            'languages' => $this->context->controller->getLanguages(),
            'id_language' => $this->context->language->id
        );
        foreach (Blockcontactinfos::$contact_fields as $field)
            $helper->tpl_vars['fields_value'][$field] = Tools::getValue($field, Configuration::get($field));
        return $helper->generateForm(array($fields_form));
    }
}
```

blockcontactinfos.tpl (added the ones with `_url`), lines 32-33:

```
{if $blockcontactinfos_address != ''}<li><pre> <a href="{$blockcontactinfos_phone_url|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">{$blockcontactinfos_address|escape:'html':'UTF-8'|nl2br}</a></pre></li>{/if}
{if $blockcontactinfos_phone != ''}<li>{l s='Tel' mod='blockcontactinfos'} <a href="tel:{$blockcontactinfos_phone_url|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">{$blockcontactinfos_phone|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</a></li>{/if}
```

Comment: if this is just mistyping on SO blockcontactinfod.php , your errors tell you about PHP syntax error, I see no Prestashop related errors. Are you sure that you have no additional code before/after class definition?

Comment: and again in provided block of code I see missed curly braces for method and class

Comment: @SergiiP I have included whole code of blockcontactinfos up in my message

Comment: if that is whole code then you missed `<?php` in first line :)

Comment: @SergiiP, unfortunatelly nope, I just skipped tons of comments at the very begening of the module and forgot to add `<?php`

Comment: and you file called `blockcontactinfos.php` and not `blockcontactinfod.php` like in post? I mean your errors tell you that there are PHP syntax problems. Try to enable showing errors in `config/defines.inc.php` and check extended error messages with traces